# Make your own folders in an app like iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Does anyone know how to make iOS folders in your own app? I'm talking about the same kind of folders you can put your apps in on an iPhone/iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find example [here](http://iphone2020.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/ios-open-folder-animation/)